# UITextView: assigning attributedText on iOS 6 leads to unexpected result

Tags: ios, uitextview, syntax-highlighting, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to implement keywords highlighting using UITextView control.
Here is what's performing in UITextView delegate method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSAttributedString *attrStr = textView.attributedText;
    NSString * string = [attrStr string];
    NSRegularExpression* regex = NameRegularExpression();
    NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrMutableStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches ) {
        [attrMutableStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:match.range];
    }
    textView.attributedText = attrMutableStr;
    textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, textView.contentSize.height);
}
```

User input parses with regexp and all extracted elements are highlighted. It works perfect on iOS 7 but absolutely crazy on iOS 6:

[image]

Any suggestions of what am I doing wrong?
By the way, it happens even if just assign exactly the same attributedString back:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSAttributedString *attrStr = textView.attributedText;
    textView.attributedText = attrStr;
}
```